# What song are these lyrics from (translated into emojis) ~ 2

Tags: knowledge, rebus, music, emoji

️️️ / ⭕

️

️

️ (2x)

- I am happy to share this wonderful song with you. You will love driving or doing any travel with this song.
- The "/" indicates there's two alternative versions of this song (there exists a variant of the song with slightly different lyrics in this line), one on the left side of the "/" and one on the right. One of the versions is also extended musically. It's good to know that (because of the 2 different versions) those 2 words must rhyme.
- It's an English song, probably prior to 1973 (you don't need to read the exact year or numbers 1973 as a hint necessarily, we are just trying to give you a cut-off date, so the song was from prior to this year).
- It's not always simply translating 1 emoji to 1 word in the lyrics: it requires a bit more interpretation, but that is because the lyrics are simple (easy grammar).
- It's the opening verse of the song.
- There are no sentences skipped (for example: it's not that lines 1 and 4 of the lyrics are represented, but not lines 2 and 3.
- It should be read (in general) from left to right and top to bottom, just like an English text.
- All words are English, there is 1 uncommon English word.
- In case your browser/device does not display the emojis, below is a screenshot of the same:

[image]

Comment: "Old Town Road" by any chance?\

Comment: No. The song we are looking for is much older. @HarikrishnanM

Comment: Great puzzle. Does the (2x) refer to just the final line?

Comment: @DrXorile Affirmative.